# Why does setting an object to be not extensible make its [[prototype]] immutable?

Tags: javascript

The [MDN - Object.preventExtensions](https://wiki.developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/preventExtensions) pages said

> This method makes the `[[prototype]]` of the target immutable; any `[[prototype]]` re-assignment will throw a `TypeError`. This behavior is specific to the internal `[[prototype]]` property, other properties of the target object will remain mutable.

And my question is:

Why does setting an object to be not extensible make its [[prototype]] immutable?
(`Object.preventExtensions()`, `Object.seal()`, `Object.freeze()` etc.)

Comment: I apologize, I'm having trouble parsing the title question. Are you asking "Why does setting an object to be not extensible make its [[prototype]] immutable?" as @Patrick is answering? I could also read it as "Why don't other methods that set objects to be not extensible also make its [[prototype]] immutable?" like `Object.seal()` or `Object.freeze()`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey your second interpretation doesn't make sense. `Object.seal()` and `Object.freeze()` also prevent extensions (and also make the [[prototype]] immutable), in addition to other effects.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Tell you what, I'll just edit the question to make it more clear, shall I? Since apparently it's too much to ask of you or the OP?

Comment: @HereticMonkey it wasn't my place to edit the question using a particular interpretation, seeing as that could potentially conflict with the author's intent. The author may not have understood your question (seeing as they may not be a native English speaker), or may have just been busy. Or maybe they just thought their question was fine as-is and didn't need to clarify since there was already an answer. Who knows. In any case, thanks for your edit, we'll see what, if anything, happens.

Comment: @HereticMonkey  Sorry for confusions, I'm not an native speaker, but @PatrickRoberts is right, `Object.seal()` and `OBject.freeze()` also make [[prototype]] immutable. If you have any idea of the clear (and precise) edition, plz let me know, i'll edit.

Answer (score 1):

If the internal `[[prototype]]` wasn't made an immutable property, you would be able to circumvent `Object.preventExtensions()` by exchanging the internal `[[prototype]]` of the object with another value using [`Object.setPrototypeOf()`](https://wiki.developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf), effectively adding all the properties on the new value to the object:

```js
let a = {};

// a now has all the properties of Array.prototype
Object.setPrototypeOf(a, Array.prototype);
a.push('foo');
console.log(a);

let b = Object.preventExtensions({});

// must not be able add properties to b in the same way
Object.setPrototypeOf(b, Array.prototype);
b.push('bar');
console.log(b);
```

Comment: Thank you bro, there only left one confusion, are the methods we added circumvently actually on its [[prototype]]?